# Javascript cannot create property 'guid' on number '100'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to trigger the `scroll` action on a `canvas` element by clicking on a link.

Here are the examples I have been following: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll

---

**JS:**

```
$('#zoom-in-button').click(function() {
    $('.vis-network canvas').scroll(0, 100);
    // $('.vis-network canvas').scroll({top: 1000});
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<a id="zoom-in-button" class="nav-button">
    +
</a>
<div class="vis-network">
    <canvas style="overflow:auto">
</div>
```

---

**Error:**

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'guid' on number '100'
    at Object.add (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: can you create jsfiddle or something similar?

Comment: You’re invoking the jquery scroll function, not the “standard” scroll method.  They are different.

Answer (score 2):

First, `$('.vis-network canvas')` is neither `window` nor `HTMLElement` - it's jQuery object. While this object has `scroll` method (in its prototype chain), it does something [**completely different**](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/):

> This method is a shortcut for `.on( "scroll", handler )` in the first
>   and second variations, and `.trigger( "scroll" )` in the third.

Note that the third case doesn't let you parameterize the event.

You're probably looking for this:

```
var canvas = $('.vis-network canvas')[0];
canvas.scrollLeft = 0;
canvas.scrollTop = 100;
```

... but it looks weird that you try to scroll the child (the contents) and not the parent. Perhaps you should actually target `$('.vis-network')` instead.

Comment: Thanks man. This fires without error. However, I'm not sure how to see what it is doing in the debugger. I tried watching the Elements tab as I click and monitorEvents(document.body); in Console. It sadly does not have the desired scroll effect.

Comment: Not sure I get you there. In any case, you should monitor canvas instead of body; scroll event doesn't bubble on elements.

Comment: hmm. maybe i am supposed to be emulating mousewheel, not scroll

Comment: No, you shouldn't; are you sure you should scroll canvas and not its parent? What are the dimensions of those elements?

Comment: scrolling the parent simply shifted it - good idea though. all child and parents are width and height 100%